# A thought that needs confirming

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Using the MVVM model, how does one person get everything to communicate to where it is ment to be ?

This would be considered the view

```
public partial class WMIControl : UserControl
{
      this.datacontext = new WMIViewModel() { };
}
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
public class WMIViewModel : WMIModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

}
```

I have Put the :WMIModel there so i can access all functions and stored data in the model, is this correct?
Here i have put all the bound property fields the perform functionality here, For Example when a checkbox is clicked

```
public string ComboBox_SelectedItem
{
    get { return _ComboBox_SelectedItem; }
    set
       {
         _ComboBox_SelectedItem = value;

         //Lets do stuff here...

         NotifyPropertyChanged("ComboBox_SelectedItem");
       }
}
```

I thought the whole point in this type of model is to put all bindings in this part of the code? please advise.

Here is the model

```
public class WMIModel
{
}
```

here i assume that we put properties  but they are not bound. the ViewModel gets the data from the Model stores it into the ViewModel properties that are bound to the View

Im probably way off base here, but i cannot figure out how everything interacts, i thought i had it worked out alright until i introduced a background worker into the mix. and then it seems that it didn't really belong anywhere. in the Model it works to a certain extent however i had to bound the property from the View to the Model so users could see the Data Populate in my TreeView.
If i put it into the ViewModel, then it is getting information from multiple computers (their WMI) when this is clearly a task for the model.

I Apologise if this seems stupid.

So to recap the questions are.

How do i setup View/ViewModel/Model to communicate with each other (Interfaces, class inheritence something else?)
a simple diagram including example code would be epic.

Where does the Background worker really belong, ViewModel or Model.

Are all bound Collections and Bound Functions (such as IsSelected) Ment to be in the ViewModel

Thank you in advance

Comment: I am not sure if i understand your question correctly, for me it seems like you are looking for a some wpf & mvmm tutorial.

Comment: i have read many, and i get the general idea, however everytime i add a new element to my project things go sideways. im just ensureing that my classes are setup correctly. should the viewmodel inherit the model or vise versa. should there be inheritance at all. or should an interface be used.

Comment: uses of interface and inheritance is all depend upon your implementation. As per my understanding MVVM pattern does not require any thing specific.

Answer (score 1):

The model-view-viewmodel is a typically WPF pattern. It consists of a view, that gets all the user input and forwards it to the viewmodel, typically by using commands. The view actively pulls the data from the viewmodel by using databinding. The model does not know about the view model.

Here is the model

```
public class WMIModel
{

}
```

Here is the viewmodel

```
public class WMIViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      public WMIModel Model {get;set;}
}
```

Here is the view

```
public partial class WMIView : UserControl
{
     public WMIView()
     { 
         InitializeComponent();
        this.datacontext = new WMIViewModel(); 

     }
}
```

For more information you can have a look into the [WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: So this would mean that if i impliment a background worker this is to be done in the ViewModel ?

Comment: NewBee: Yes you can say that, though it is much depend upon the kind operation being performed

Comment: it performs a WMI WQL query on multiple computers depending on what the user has asked for. so a Select statement on around about 500 computers.

Comment: You can use the background worker in viewmodel, i don;t see any issue on using background worker in viewmodel.

Comment: If Background worker is doing task regarding UI Update, you must write it in ViewModel. Otherwise you have both options - Model or ViewModel.

Comment: However a better place for the `BackgroundWorker` would be outside of the `ViewModel`. Does the ViewModel really expose anything about the `BackgroundWorker` to the UI, No. So instead consider using an MVVMC pattern, http://www.trelford.com/blog/post/MVMMC-e28093-MVVM-grows-a-Controller.aspx

Comment: Interesting concept. this is something i think i need. a way the data can be retrieved and once completed notify my ViewModel to process the data captured.